# Can you find it?

Tags: wordplay

Can you find a three-letter word which when preceded by any of A,B,D or E forms a four-letter word?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> What about the word "yes"?

> Preceded by A, B, D and E, we get ayes, byes, dyes and eyes respectively.

Comment: So the answer to the question posed is..."Yes."

Comment: @Exal one of the rare case where answering it literally also answers the intended question.

Comment: The symmetry/reflexivity is why I was so very pleased with this - little things